# Snowflake creating/replacing a stored procedure created by another role

Tags: stored-procedures, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

1. I have a stored procedure (`return_greater(int, int)`) in Snowflake which is created by the `SYSADMIM` role.
2. I also have a custom role (`readwrite`) which is granted to the built-in `SYSADMIN` role.

Below is the stored procedure.

```
create or replace procedure return_greater(number_1 integer, number_2 integer)
returns integer not null
language sql
as
$$
begin
  if (number_1 > number_2) then
    return number_1;
  else
    return number_2;
  end if;
end;
$$
;
```

I have granted all privileges on the stored procedure to the role `readwrite` using the below command.

```
grant all privileges on procedure DatabaseName.SchemaName.return_greater(int, int) to role READWRITE;
```

Below are the grants on the stored procedure.
[image]

Now when I try to create/replace the stored proc using the `readwrite` role I am getting the below error -

[image]

My question is how can I make the `readwrite` role, create/replace the stored proc, without actually granting the ownership of the stored procedure to that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: not possible without transferring the ownership.

The long answer: Authorization to execute CREATE  statements comes from the primary role only. When an object is created, its ownership is set to the currently active primary role. However, for any other SQL action, any permission granted to any active primary or secondary role can be used to authorize the action.

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html).

Comment: Interesting, that CREATE statements need authorisation from the primary role only. That makes sense. 
There is just one follow up question which I have. Let's say I have a procedure created by the `readwrite` role, then will the `SYSADMIN` role able to create/replace that procedure, since the `readwrite` role ultimately granted to the built-in `SYSADMIN` role. Will `SYSADMIN` be able to change the definition of that procedure?

Comment: Yes, SYSADMIN will be able to create/replace that procedure, but based on my long answer this action would also transfer the ownership to SYSADMIN which means role READWRITE won't be able to create/replace the procedure anymore after (would get a SQL compilation error) unless SYSADMIN drops the procedure.